# Pmi Client is not created while using with sun java instead of IBM java

Tags: websphere, monitoring

My task to monitor the IBM Websphere through pmi client.Pmi client is an agent provided by the IBM to get MBeans and is running under IBM Java. I tried it to run under Sun java. But, it fails to create the Pmiclient. Did Anyone come across this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The IBM JRE has slightly customized classes. This is unfortunately not uncommon with PMI (and also JMX by the way) when working with different WebSphere Application Server versions.

There are hacks around involving copying the relevant IBM implementations and running them with the Sun/Oracle JRE but I don't think that is valid according to the licensing terms. What you really should do is to use the IBM provided JRE.

If you want a riskless shortcut you will build an applicaton (perhaps EJB or servlets) that runs on the WebSphere Application Server and exposes the results from PMI via custom interface. For instance web service.